# How can I speed up this nested loop (Index by date?)

Tags: python, datetime

dataset looks like this:

```py
    email               event_date                  event_type 
0   4867784685125632    2015-10-26 21:38:03.911350  delivered   
1   5352432066363392    2015-10-26 21:37:57.871980  delivered   
2   6024938649550848    2015-10-26 21:37:57.853210  purchase    
3   6191500064980992    2015-10-26 21:37:58.867800  delivered   
4   4867784685125632    2015-10-28 21:37:56.331130  purchase
```

Essentially there are a number of rows that share a hashed email (email) value.  For each row where event type = delivered, I need to count the number of rows where event_type = purchase that share the same email address, and take place within a 5 day period following the date in the original row.

I've worked out a way to do this where I split this df into separate delivered and purchased dataframes, and then use a nested loop to search through both -- but it's really inefficient and taking forever.

```py
attributed_purchases = []

count = 0

for idx_e, row_e in delivered.iterrows():
    purch = 0
    rev = 0

    for idx_p, row_p, in purchased.iterrows():

        if delivered.loc[idx_e, 'email'] != purchased.loc[idx_p, 'email']:
            pass

        elif (purchased.loc[idx_p, 'event_date'] >= delivered.loc[idx_e, 'event_date']) and purchased.loc[idx_p, 'event_date'] <= (delivered.loc[idx_e, 'event_date'] + timedelta(days=5)):
            purch += 1

            print('I just found a purchase')

    attributed_purchases.append(purch)

    count += 1

    print(f'Completed iteration {count}')

delivered['attributed_purchases'] = attributed_purchases
```

First loop iterates through rows in the delivered dataframe.  For each row, it loops through the purchased dataframe and first checks to see if the emails match.  If they do, it checks to see if the date is within 5 days after and increments the counter.  After iterating through the purchased dataframe, it appends the count to a list and jumps to the next iteration in the first for loop.

This works, but I'm working with a large amount of data and it's taking far too long.

I'm sure there are numerous ways to speed this up.  Perhaps if I index based on date?  Any help is appreciated!

Let me know if you need more information.

Comment: Why split the data like that and use nested loops in the first place? If you just loop over the data oldest-newest, you can meet the requirement without any inner loop. Track which `purchase` hasn't yet had a matching `delivered` in a dict `{email: date purchased}`, and then when you do find the delivery, `del` it from that dict. If that delivery happens to be within 5 days, increment the counter.

If there's any completely undelivered, they will accrue in the dict, but you can always do a cleanup operation on it once every 5000 loops or whatever makes sense, if needed.

Comment: The problem is that one email address may have a number of purchases associated with it, so I can't use the hashed email as a dictionary key.  Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Hard without knowing more specific requirements, but some high-level suggestions -

1. Use `break` once you've found the purchase data in inner loop, so that you're not needlessly processing all of the remaining items.
2. Cleanup the list of purchases as deliveries are filled, so that it shrinks over time, and future iterations of outer loop aren't processing items that have already been attributed.

Per my comment though, I still think a simple single-loop approach would be a lot more efficient, and to deal with multiple potentially overlapping purchases for a single email you just need to store them each as a list (`defaultdict(list)` used for convenience), and manage those lists as you go. This also ensures that a single delivery is not fulfilling multiple purchases, although if that is desired just change the whole `try` block to something like `count += bool(pending[ehash])`

```
import datetime
from collections import defaultdict

emails = ((e[0], datetime.datetime.strptime(e[1], '%Y-%m-%d'), e[2])
    for e in (
      (1, '2019-01-01', 'delivered'),  # ignored, no prior purchase
      (1, '2019-01-02', 'purchase'),
      (1, '2019-01-03', 'purchase'),
      (1, '2019-01-04', 'delivered'),  # matches [1], count == 1
      (1, '2019-01-05', 'purchase'),
      (1, '2019-01-06', 'delivered'),  # matches [2], count == 2
      (1, '2019-01-20', 'delivered')   # ignored, too long since last purchase
    )
)
count = 0
pending = defaultdict(list)

for (ehash, date, status) in sorted(emails, key=lambda e: e[1]):

    # record a purchase awaiting delivery
    if status == 'purchase':
        pending[ehash].append(date)

    elif status == 'delivered':
        # purge any purchases for this email > 5days old
        pending[ehash] = [p_date for p_date in pending[ehash]
                         if p_date > date - datetime.timedelta(days=5)]

        # then the next oldest (<5days) also deleted, and increments the count
        try:
            del pending[ehash][0]
            count += 1
        except IndexError:
            pass # No valid purchase for this delivery

print(count)
```